# is a solid torus homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology

The question is in the title. A solid torus is $S^1 \times D^2$, and while it is homotopic to $S^1$ (since $D^2$ is contractible), I suspect it is not homeomorphic to $S^1$. But I don't know how to prove there is no homoeomorphism from $S^1 \to D^2$ to $S^1$. From cardinality considerations there is no bijective map, let alone homeomorphism, $D^2 \to pt$, but I don't know if a a cardinality argument works for my case of $S^1$ and $S^1 \times D^2$ .., both have cardinality $\aleph_1$, and I don't know how to compare $\aleph_1 \aleph_1$ and $ \aleph_1$...maybe they are equal?

Comment: If you replace homeomorphism with homotopy you will get a different answer. Cardinality is usually the wrong argument to prove two things \emph{are} homeomorphic, unless they are finite.

Comment: certainly they are not homeomorphic but they have the same **homotopy type** which make them almost topologically the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show that if you remove any two points from $S^1$, you get a disconnected space, but if you remove any two points from $S^1\times D^2$, you get a connected space.

Comment: very nice. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solid torus is a manifold of dimension $3$, whereas $S^1$ is a manifold of dimension $1$.

Comment: oh, yes, of course. silly me. thanks.